# cmp length of text to an integer in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to compare the length of `Hello, World!\n` to an integer in asm, but **nasm** gives me an error `invalid combination of opcode and operands`. I googled `cmp` and it seems that I write this instruction valid, so why this happens?

```
msg db "Hello, World!", 0x00, 0xA ; null-terminator + \n
msglen equ $ - msg ; length of msg (15)
```

```
cmp msglen, 15 ; compare msglen to 15
je is_equal ; jump to is_equal - if equal
```

Comment: You can't use `cmp 15, 15` either and that's the same thing. But why are you doing this? The only time this comes up is when the comparison is useless

Comment: @harold wdym `useless`? I just want to compare length of msg to an integer. what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `cmp imm, imm` does not exist, `cmp` can take an immediate operand but only one. It's useless because you're comparing two known numbers, the outcome is predetermined.

Comment: Comparing an assemble-time constant only makes sense at assemble time; it would be pointless to do it every run.  I think `%if msglen == 15` / `jmp is_equal` / `%endif` should work to emit an unconditional jmp or nothing, depending on that compile-time condition.  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.4